# Keep iPhone display on while connected to mac

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, display, settings, shortcuts-app

Is there a native setting or a shortcut, that I can use to keep my iPhone display always on until I lock it, while it is connected to my macbook?

This would be really helpful while developing apps for iPhone.

I don't want to turn on the screen all the time, only while connected to this macbook or if it is not possible, than while charging.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a personal automation that start when the phone is connected to power. Unfortunately AFAIK there is no way to change the auto-lock timer from shortcuts, the only thing you can do is open settings when you connect to power so that it's slightly faster to change the setting.

Other than that the only thing you can do is send a feedback to apple to get access to more settings using shortcuts.

The only "hack" I can think of is to start playing a black, silent video with PiP, but that seems like a lot of work for a very bad and annoying solution, since if you're doing dev work you probably don't want a black square in your screen.